# Neutrality for sentiment analysis in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes

I have built a pretty basic naive bayes over apache spark and using mllib of course. But I have a few clarifications on what exactly neutrality means.

From what I understand, in a given dataset there are pre-labeled sentences which comprise of the necessary classes, let's take 3 for example below.

```
0-> Negative sentiment
1-> Positive sentiment
2-> Neutral sentiment
```

This neutral is pre-labeled in the training set itself.

Is there any other form of neutrality handling. Suppose if there are no neutral sentences available in the dataset then is it possible that I can calculate it from the scale of probability like

```
0.0 - 0.4 => Negative
0.4- - 0.6 => Neutral
0.6 - 1.0 => Positive
```

Is such kind of mapping possible in spark. I searched around but could not find any. The `NaiveBayesModel` class in the RDD API has a `predict` method which just returns a double that is mapped according to the training set i.e if only 0,1 is there it will return only 0,1 and not in a scaled manner such as 0.0 - 1.0 as above.

Any pointers/advice on this would be incredibly helpful.

Edit - 1

Sample code

```
//Performs tokenization,pos tagging and then lemmatization
//Returns a array of string
val tokenizedString = Util.tokenizeData(text)
val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
//Returns a double 
//According to the training set 1.0 => Positive, 0.0 => Negative
val status = model.predict(hashingTF.transform(tokenizedString.toSeq))
if(status == 1.0) "Positive" else "Negative"
```

Sample dataset content

```
1,Awesome movie
0,This movie sucks
```

Of course the original dataset contains more longer sentences, but this should be enough for explanations I guess

Using the above code I am calculating. My question is the same

1) Neutrality handling in dataset
In the above dataset if I am adding another category such as 
2,This movie can be enjoyed by kids

For arguments sake, lets assume that it is a neutral review, then the `model.predict` method will give either 1.0,0.0,2.0 based on the passed in sentence.

2) Using the `model.predictProbabilities` it gives an array of doubles, but I am not sure in what order it gives the result i.e index 0 is for negative or for positive? With three features i.e Negative,Positive,Neutral then in what order will that method return the predictions?

Comment: we need to see your code to help here. depending how you build your ml pipeline (if you did use a pipeline), the labels may be available through your stringIndexer stage.

Comment: @PascalSoucy : I have added code examples and more detailed explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been helpful to have the code that builds the model (for your example to work, the 0.0 from the dataset must be converted to 0.0 as a Double in the model, either after indexing it with a StringIndexer stage, or if you converted that from the file), but assuming that this code works:

```
val status = model.predict(hashingTF.transform(tokenizedString.toSeq))
if(status == 1.0) "Positive" else "Negative"
```

Then yes, it means the probabilities at index 0 is that of negative and at 1 that of positive (it's a bit strange and there must be a reason, but everything is a double in ML, even feature and category indexes). If you have something like this in your code:

```
val labelIndexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("sentiment")
  .setOutputCol("indexedsentiment")
  .fit(trainingData)
```

Then you can use `labelIndexer.labels` to identify the labels (probability at index 0 is for labelIndexer.labels at index 0.

Now regarding your other questions.

1. Neutrality can mean two different things. Type 1: a review contains as much positive and negative words Type 2: there is (almost) no sentiment expressed.
2. A Neutral category can be very helpful if you want to manage Type 2. If that is the case, you need neutral examples in your dataset. Naive Bayes is not a good classifier to apply thresholding on the probabilities in order to determine Type 2 neutrality.
3. Option 1: Build a dataset (if you think you will have to deal with a lot of Type 2 neutral texts). The good news is, building a neutral dataset is not too difficult. For instance you can pick random texts that are not movie reviews and assume they are neutral. It would be even better if you could pick content that is closely related to movies (but neutral), like a dataset of movie synopsis. You could then create a multi-class Naive Bayes classifier (between neutral, positive and negative) or a hierarchical classifier (first step is a binary classifier that determines whether a text is a movie review or not, second step to determine the overall sentiment).
4. Option 2 (can be used to deal with both Type 1 and 2). As I said, Naive Bayes is not very great to deal with thresholds on the probabilities, but you can try that. Without a dataset though, it will be difficult to determine the thresholds to use. Another approach is to identify the number of words or stems that have a significant polarity. One quick and dirty way to achieve that is to query your classifier with each individual word and count the number of times it returns "positive" with a probability significantly higher than the negative class (discard if the probabilities are too close to each other, for instance within 25% - a bit of experimentations will be needed here). At the end, you may end up with say 20 positive words vs 15 negative ones and determine it is neutral because it is balanced or if you have 0 positive and 1 negative, return neutral because the count of polarized words is too low.

Good luck and hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks..that helped. I was using `val model : NaiveBayesModel = new NaiveBayes().fit(finalDF)` where finalDF is obtained after tokenization-> ngrams filtering and then transformed using hashingTF. I was getting weird results when trying to predict neutrality when there was none in the dataset and as you said naive bayes does not seem to be a good fit for it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand the problem but:

- prior in Naive Bayes is computed from the data and cannot be set manually.
- in MLLib you can use `predictProbabilities` to obtain class probabilities.
- in ML you can use `setThresholds` to set prediction threshold for each class.

Comment: Yes, I saw that method, but the comment on the code is pretty high level. It returns an array of two elements, but I am not able to understand which one is related to positive and which is related to negative?

Comment: `[P(c = 0), P(c = 1), ..., P(c = n)]`

Comment: Ok, so is it numbered in that order? So if I have 0,1 (0-negative,1-positive) in training set and `predictProbabilities` returns [0.86777,0.012344] is it guaranteed that 0 i.e the negative probability is 0.86/86%